# "Correct antiderivative" for the integral $\int 2e^{\tan^{-1}x+x^2+\ln x}\left(2+\frac{2x^3+2x+1}{x+1/x}\right) dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate $$I=\int 2e^{\tan^{-1}x+x^2+\ln x}\left(2+\dfrac{2x^3+2x+1}{x+1/x}\right) dx$$

This was an MCQ question, and the solver got the answer as $$I=xe^{\tan^{-1}x+x^2+\ln x}+C$$

However the (apparently) [correct answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPfIK.png) is $$I=x^2e^{\tan^{-1}x+x^2}+C$$
$$$$The primary discussion was on whether the two functions are equivalent or not, and if not, then which function is the correct antiderivative. At first sight, these two alternatives might appear to be the same, but they are not:  $xe^{\tan^{-1}x+x^2+\ln x}+C$ is not defined at $x=0$; $x^2e^{\tan^{-1}x+x^2}+C$ is. I also noticed that the integrand is defined for $x>0$ (and not at $x=0$).

I suspect that somewhere the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) is to be used, however, I am unable to use it correctly.

Comment: Isnt $ xe^{\tan^{-1}x+x^2+\ln x} = xe^{\tan^{-1}x+x^2}\cdot e^{\ln(x)} = x^2e^{\tan^{-1}x+x^2}$?

Comment: A similar argument could be made for $y =x$ . It is defined at $0$. But $y =e^{\ln(x)}$ is undefined at 0

Comment: My point is that one must simplify the given functions  to their simplest form before doing any other work to it(such as finding its domain). Feel free to correct me if i'm wrong. Perhaps i might be wrong. I think it would be best if you graphed the functions to check if they are similar.

Comment: Note that the two functions you are concerned about the equality of when $x \neq 0$. This is like asking for an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$. It's all fine to say $\sqrt{x}$. We usually don't worry what happens to $\sqrt{x}$ at zero since we'd be taking a limit there anyway so it would be an improper integral :)

Comment: perhaps the answer depends on the way you calculated the integral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the domain of the function $ 2e^{\tan^{-1}x+x^2+\ln x}\left(2+\dfrac{2x^3+2x+1}{x+1/x}\right)$ being integrated is $(0, \infty)$.

Therefore, the antiderivative you get $F(x)$ is understood to be defined/restricted on some interval inside $(0, \infty)$.

This makes both answers correct, but if you want to be precise you should emphasize that their domains are $(0, \infty)$.